# Split customernames entered in input box

Tags: javascript

```
 <p id="output"> customer name you enter will be shown here </p>  
 <input type="text" id="allnames" placeholder="enter all names" /> 
    <button onclick="process()">
  separate
</button>

 <script>
   function process(){
      var nameArray=[];
      var inputName="";
      inputName=document.getElementById("allnames").value;
      nameArray=inputName.split(",");

      var xyz="";
      for (var i=0; i<nameArray.length;i++){
        xyz=xyz+nameArray[i]+"<br>";


      }
      return xyz; 
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=process(xyz); 
    };
</script>
```

So basically the console says "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.split ()"

Why is that? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `function process(){ ...   .innerHTML=process(xyz);` What are you trying to do here? `process` will recursively call itself until the stack overflows. Please post a full [MCVE] and the expected output

Comment: Hi I am trying to split whatever written in the input box. (have edited it a little bit, hope it's better now)

Comment: Your return is inside of the for statement. it should be outside the for statement.

Also what is `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=process(xyz);` suppsoed to do?

Comment: Hi, I want to display the nameArray in the paragraph whose id="output".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
 <input id='allnames'/>
 <p id="output"> customer name you enter will be shown here </p>  

    <button onclick="process()">
  separate
</button>

<script>
function process() {
  let inputs = document.body.querySelector('#allnames').value.split(',');
  let output = '';
  inputs.forEach( name => output += name + '<br>' );
  let outputEl = document.body.querySelector('#output');
  outputEl.innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

## EDIT (asked)

```html
     <input id='allnames'/>
     <p id="output"> customer name you enter will be shown here </p>  

        <button onclick="process()">
      separate
    </button>

    <script>
    function process() {
      var inputEl = document.getElementById('allnames');
      var inputs = inputEl.value.split(',');
      var output = '';
      for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
       output += inputs[i] + '<br>';
      }
      var outputEl = document.getElementById('output');
      outputEl.innerHTML = output;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you. Is it possible not to use let statement? Our teacher has not taught us that.

Comment: yep in that case you can write a 'var' instead of a 'let' but 'let' and 'const' are a better practise than the good old 'var'

Comment: just to ad var is global scoped and so if you declare var inside of a block it will exist outside the block as well whereas let only exists within the block is is declared

Comment: Sorry Simon, I am too "beginner" to understand your code. Is it possible for you to revise the code I wrote using the basic methods? I really can't understand.

Comment: check my EDIT ;)

Comment: FIY : if you write a return statement in a function, none of the line below will execute.
Basically in your original code you have to delete the "return line"  and write :
`document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xyz;` instead of `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=process(xyz);`

Comment: So even if I wrote document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=process(xyz); outside of the function it will still stop executing because of the return statement above?

Comment: if your write it outside of your function this line will not be executed by the button click event, so if you want to do it that way i suggest you this : https://jsfiddle.net/ae5o1bpv/  and be careful I change the `onclick` attribute of the button

Comment: Thank you so much Simon! It's so much clearer now. Just one more question: is process(xyz) meaningless in this case?